# Formula To Remove Duplicates based On Two Columns

Tags: excel-formula

I have two columns and i would like to remove duplicates. If I use the function in excel , too much information will be removed
For example I have the following

```
 ColumnA ColumnB

  E1       ABC

  E1       ABC

  E1       ABC

  E1       CBA

  E2       TTT

  E2       TTT

  E2       JJJ
```

What i would like to do is remove duplicates based on two column criteria so i would have the following

```
 ColumnA ColumnB

  E1       ABC

  E1       CBA

  E2       TTT

  E2       JJJ
```

I have tried the following formula
=IF(A2=A3,1)*AND(B2=B3,1)

This will put a 1 in some cells if there are duplicates (which could then be deleted) but does not really test for all duplicates hence my formula is not correct.

Comment: Why don't you just use the built in "remove duplicates" function?

Comment: Silly me !!! - I was using the built in function but choosing one column only, as soon as i chose both columns i have the desired result